# Recursively dividing up a list, based on the endpoints

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, recursion

Here is what I am trying to do.
Take the list:

```py
list1 = [0,2]
```

This list has start point 0 and end point 2.
Now, if we were to take the midpoint of this list, the list would become:

```py
list1 = [0,1,2]
```

Now, if we were to recursively split up the list again (take the midpoints of the midpoints), the list would becomes:

```py
list1 = [0,.5,1,1.5,2]
```

I need a function that will generate lists like this, preferably by keeping track of a variable. So, for instance, let's say there is a variable, n, that keeps track of something. When n = 1, the list might be [0,1,2] and when n = 2, the list might be [0,.5,1,1.5,2], and I am going to increment the value of to keep track of how many times I have divided up the list.

I know you need to use recursion for this, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Should be something like this:

```py
def recursive(list1,a,b,n):
  """list 1 is a list of values, a and b are the start
     and end points of the list, and n is an int representing
     how many times the list needs to be divided"""
   int mid = len(list1)//2
 stuff
```

Could someone help me write this function? Not for homework, part of a project I'm working on that involves using mesh analysis to divide up rectangle into parts.

This is what I have so far:

```py
def recursive(a,b,list1,n):
  w = b - a
  mid = a +  w / 2
  left = list1[0:mid]
  right = list1[mid:len(list1)-1]
  return recursive(a,mid,list1,n) + mid + recursive(mid,b,list1,n)
```

but I'm not sure how to incorporate n into here.

NOTE: The list1 would initially be [a,b] - I would just manually enter that but I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Comment: did you try anything yourself for writing this

Comment: yep, editing it right now, give me a min

Comment: okay updated - i'm just trying to figure out how to incorporate n mainly, like how to tell it to stop

Comment: you can use a variable `n`, once it reaches that value, then `break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've generated some interesting answers. Here are two more.

My first uses an iterator to avoid
slicing the list and is recursive because that seems like the most natural formulation.

```
def list_split(orig, n):
    if not n:
        return orig
    else:
        li = iter(orig)
        this = next(li)
        result = [this]
        for nxt in li:
            result.extend([(this+nxt)/2, nxt])
            this = nxt
        return list_split(result, n-1)

for i in range(6):
    print(i, list_split([0, 2], i))
```

This prints

```
0 [0, 2]
1 [0, 1.0, 2]
2 [0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2]
3 [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2]
4 [0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1.0, 1.125, 1.25, 1.375, 1.5, 1.625, 1.75, 1.875, 2]
5 [0, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.1875, 0.25, 0.3125, 0.375, 0.4375, 0.5, 0.5625, 0.625, 0.6875, 0.75, 0.8125, 0.875, 0.9375, 1.0, 1.0625, 1.125, 1.1875, 1.25, 1.3125, 1.375, 1.4375, 1.5, 1.5625, 1.625, 1.6875, 1.75, 1.8125, 1.875, 1.9375, 2]
```

My second is based on the observation that recursion isn't necessary if you always start from two elements. Suppose those elements are `mn` and `mx`. After `N` applications of the split operation you will have `2^N+1` elements in it, so the numerical distance between the elements will be `(mx-mn)/(2**N)`.

Given this information it should therefore be possible to deterministically compute the elements of the array, or even easier to [use `numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) like this:

```
def grid(emin, emax, N):
    return numpy.linspace(emin, emax, 2**N+1)
```

This appears to give the same answers, and will probably serve you best in the long run.

Comment: Interesting, yeah recursion seems to be the way to go for this one imo, thanks for the neat solution!

Comment: A pleasure. I realised a long time ago that when Python code is easy to read it's easy to understand, so I try to keep things simple even though it takes a little longer.

Comment: In 3.8, rather than `this = next(li); result = [this]` we will be able to write `result = [this := next(li)]` thanks to PEP 572.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some arithmetic and slicing to figure out the size of the result, and fill it efficiently with values.

While not required, you can implement a recursive call by wrapping this functionality in a simple helper function, which checks what iteration of splitting you are on, and splits the list further if you are not at your limit.

---

```
def expand(a):
    """
    expands a list based on average values between every two values
    """
    o = [0] * ((len(a) * 2) - 1)
    o[::2] = a
    o[1::2] = [(x+y)/2 for x, y in zip(a, a[1:])]
    return o

def rec_expand(a, n):
    if n == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return rec_expand(expand(a), n-1)
```

---

***In action***

```
>>> rec_expand([0, 2], 2)
[0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2]

>>> rec_expand([0, 2], 4)
[0,
 0.125,
 0.25,
 0.375,
 0.5,
 0.625,
 0.75,
 0.875,
 1.0,
 1.125,
 1.25,
 1.375,
 1.5,
 1.625,
 1.75,
 1.875,
 2]
```

Comment: I think a more helpful base case for your recursion is `n == 0` in which case you should just return `a`.

Comment: Oh okay that's clever, was not expecting that route! I see how it works though, just need the helper function for recursion, thanks so much!

Comment: You don't *need* the helper function, but it makes it clearer how the recursion is working

Comment: Agree - it's often helpful for beginners to see the difference between the recursion control logic an the actual computation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a for loop

```
import numpy as np

def add_midpoints(orig_list, n):
    for i in range(n):
        new_list = []
        for j in range(len(orig_list)-1):
            new_list.append(np.mean(orig_list[j:(j+2)]))

        orig_list = orig_list + new_list
        orig_list.sort()

    return orig_list

add_midpoints([0,2],1)
[0, 1.0, 2]
add_midpoints([0,2],2)
[0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2]
add_midpoints([0,2],3)
[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this totally non-recursively and without looping.  What we're doing here is just making a binary scale between two numbers like on most Imperial system rulers.

```
def binary_scale(start, stop, level):
    length = stop - start
    scale = 2 ** level
    return [start + i * length / scale for i in range(scale + 1)]
```

In use:

```
>>> binary_scale(0, 10, 0)
[0.0, 10.0]
>>> binary_scale(0, 10, 2)
[0.0, 2.5, 5.0, 7.5, 10.0]
>>> binary_scale(10, 0, 1)
[10.0, 5.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: What if they start with the list `[0, 3, 1]`.  I agree that you can do this all in one step, but this only accounts for a single start/stop value where `start > stop`.  Still a useful answer however.

Comment: What do you mean, "and without looping"? Isn't `[... for i in range(...)]` a loop?

Comment: @user3483203 based on the posters question and sample code, that's the use case.

Comment: @cdlane It may be implemented as a loop under the hood, but list comprehensions are a more preferred pattern and typically run faster as well.

Comment: It's not "under the hood", if you can see the `for`.  Something like `map()` is a loop "under the hood".  A *preferred* loop syntax is still a loop.  A *faster* loop syntax is still a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Fun with anti-patterns:

```
def expand(a, n):
    for _ in range(n):

        a[:-1] = sum(([a[i], (a[i] + a[i + 1]) / 2] for i in range(len(a) - 1)), [])

    return a

print(expand([0, 2], 2))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
[0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2]
%
```